# Card setting into two columns SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to set card view vertically into two columns.
I have created two views - One is Product Main Catalog and second is for Catalog Details (which is the card).

I tried to call Catalog Details from Product Main Catalog according to data. I need to display card/cell in two columns but its not showing.

**CardView**

```
 var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image("Image2")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()**
                VStack {
                    Text("Product 1")
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
                
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 176, maxWidth: 176, minHeight: 176, maxHeight: 176)**
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 230/255))
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
```

**Main - I am calling CardView here**

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderView()
            HStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.productCode) { cat in
                    HStack {
                        CardView(type: .mediumProductCardView(viewModel: ProductCatalogViewModel(product: cat)))
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                Text("Products")
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design:.rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                Text("The quest for a balanced life")
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            //Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Result:**

[currently show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z28Rd.png)

**Want two columns like this:**

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1tpr.png)

Comment: Use [LazyVGrid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid).

Comment: @Asad I tried it but same result

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and made a few changes, and it appears to be working. If you like, I can paste the solution.

Comment: @Asad sure I can right test it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LazyVGrid and commented out the static frame of CardView. Change the grid size to meet your needs.

```
struct CardView: View {
    let index: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: "photo.badge.plus.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                VStack {
                    Text("Product \(index)")
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }

            }
            //.frame(minWidth: 176, maxWidth: 176, minHeight: 176, maxHeight: 176)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 230/255))
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                Text("Products")
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design:.rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                Text("The quest for a balanced life")
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            //Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HeaderView()

                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 5), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 5)], spacing: 10) {

                    ForEach(0..<7) { i in
                        CardView(index: i)
                    }
                }
                .padding(5)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** [image]

Comment: How to fix position of Image in case of two lines text comes?

Comment: You may use `Spacer` in the second `VStack` of `CardView` to push image and text upwards if it meets your requirements.